# Stability of MIMO system by system matrix eigenvalues

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, control-theory, stability-theory

I have a MIMO LTI system described by 
$\begin{cases}\mathbf{\dot{x}=Ax+Bu}\\
\mathbf{y=Cx} \end{cases}$
If it is controllable, can I conclude system's BIBO stability provided that all eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}$ are left half-plane located?
I know it is true for SISO systems, however, I could not find any reference that clearly asserts such a theorem for MIMO systems.
Thanks.

Comment: You need both the controllability and the observability, in both the SISO and MIMO cases.

Comment: @KBS, Thanks. Then, LHP eigenvalues ensure stability for MIMO Systems?

Comment: The eigenvalues need to be in the open left half-plane.

Comment: @KBS, Could you name a good reference on this topic for me please?

Comment: Any book on multivariable control would do the job. For instance, the book by Skogestad and Postlethwaite.